# How to get lowest price from custom fields of posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

Here is my Code.

It is get sub category from main category. and from sub category having different posts related about different products. Now issue it this that i want lowest price value from custom field that i define. so i should i do it to get lowest/min value.

```
<div>
    <?php 
    $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of='.$cat.'&hide_empty');
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
    ?>
    <div class="cat-con">
          <?php
          $subCatId=sprintf('%s',$subcategory->term_id); //the_content(); 
          query_posts('cat='.$subCatId.'&order=ASC&meta_key=price&orderby=meta_value_number');
          while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

          /************************************************************************/
          // this part of code is getting me price of custom fields   
          $price=$post->ID; 
          $price = get_post_meta($price, 'price', true);
          if ($price <= 3500) {
          $minPrice=$price;
          /************************************************************************/
          ?>
              <div class="cat-img">
                  <?php $postID=$post->ID; $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src (get_post_thumbnail_id( $pageID ),'medium', true) ; ?>
                  <img width="445" height="209" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <div class="cat-heading">
                  <?php echo sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>',get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));?></a>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <div class="cat-con-text">
                  <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>

              <div>
                  <div class="floatright">
                      <a href="<?php echo sprintf('%s',get_category_link($subcategory->term_id)); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' );?>/images/btn-view.png" alt="" /></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cat-price">Price Start From &pound;<?php echo $minPrice?></div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
                  <?php    
          } // end if $price
          endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php } //end foreach; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!--End Category-->
```

Comment: Please can you format the source, that it easier to read. Current it is hard to understand your template code. Also it is fine, if you have more descriptions to the source.

Comment: now i have updated

Comment: Now I have updated and I hope you see it, it is better. The source is from one template file and the important topic for you is marked with comments inside this source.

Comment: Also a hint; don't use `$post->ID`; use `get_the_ID()`. You set very often the var new with same value ID, not useful etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is badly broken in a couple of place and potentially flawed in a couple of others.

```
$price=$post->ID; 
$price = get_post_meta($price, 'price', true);
i0 ($price <= 3500) {
   $minPrice=$price;
```

- Line 1: Not broken but why not just use $post->ID? Setting that to a variable named `$price` is confusing and unnecessary.
- Line 2: Passing the `true` parameter means `get_post_meta` will only return a single value. This will break if there are multiple prices. I don't know if that is the case.
- Line 3: `if` is misspelled. This would be a fatal error. Secondly, your question is about finding the **lowest** value but you are looking for less than or equal to a **static** 3500. There is an inconsistency. I am assuming you want the lowest value.
- Finally: You don't close the `if` conditions. There should be a closing `}`. This is another fatal error.

So, if you are trying to get the lowest value per post do this:

```
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price');
$minPrice=min($price);
```

If you are trying to get the lowest price from all of the posts in your loop do this:

```
$price = get_post_meta($price, 'price', true);
// initialize $minPrice to some high value before the Loop starts
if ($price < $minPrice) {
    $minPrice=$price;
}
```

Comment: The `if ($price` was a problem of my edit, Sorry. But the code was not readable and I have change small on to see the source in one code block on the question.

Comment: i am get sub-categaries and there all posts which belong to sub-categaries. now i want to display that post which has lowest price

Comment: `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$price1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", false);
echo $minPrice = min($price1);
endwhile;
`

Comment: `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$price1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, "price", false);
echo $minPrice = min($price1);
endwhile;
`

/********************************************/
It is getting me value array
Array ( [0] => 2500 )
Array ( [0] => 3500 )

Comment: Is your `$price` value an array (serialized array) in the database? I tested this and I do not get an array.